# Trim values after forward flash

Tags: json, jolt

Source JSON:

```json
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "name": "accounts/189134493",
      "createTime": "2021-02-08T08:55:53.722Z",
      "updateTime": "2021-02-08T08:55:53.722Z"
    },
    {
      "name": "accounts/192303354",
      "createTime": "2021-03-16T14:22:04.865Z",
      "updateTime": "2021-03-16T14:22:04.865Z"
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": "APDpoXMhpjzh_oJqiqip6upnMH"
}
```

Expected:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1891344",
    "createTime": "2021-02-08T08:55:53.722Z",
    "updateTime": "2021-02-08T08:55:53.722Z"
  },
  {
    "id": "1923033",
    "createTime": "2021-03-16T14:22:04.865Z",
    "updateTime": "2021-03-16T14:22:04.865Z"
  }
]
```

I was only able to unnest values from `accounts` array with simple shift operation:

```json
"spec": {
  "*": {
    "*": {
      "*": "[&1].&"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I need to grab values from `name`, and get value after `accounts/` and store it as `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can successively use ***split*** and ***join*** functions within a **modify** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "accounts": {
        "*": {
          "name_": "=split('accounts/',@(1,name))", // split the pieces by the provided literal "accounts/"
          "id": "=join('',@(1,name_))" // combine the components of the newly formed arrays to yield string type values
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "accounts": {
        "*": {
          "nam*": ""
        }
      },
      "nextPageToken": ""
    }
  }
]
```

the **demo** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

**Edit** : if the value of name attribute has multiple slashes as in the commented example

```json
"name":"accounts/189134493/properties/123"
```

and want to extract the piece after the last slash such as

```json
"id":"123"
```

then prefer using the following spec which contains ***lastElement*** function :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "accounts": {
        "*": {
          "name_": "=split('/',@(1,name))",
          "id": "=lastElement(@(1,name_))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "accounts": {
        "*": {
          "nam*": ""
        }
      },
      "nextPageToken": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: What if there will be `accounts/189134493/properties/123`. I need `123` as id? Thanks in advance!

Comment: well, I've just edited @fujidaon